# Opening a jQuery UI Dialog with dynamic links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have links generated dynamically based on content in a db.

The links end up looking like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/Updates/LoadArticle?NewsId=3" id="article">Article 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Updates/LoadArticle?NewsId=2" id="article">Article 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Updates/LoadArticle?NewsId=1" id="article">Article 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

The script I pieced together is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#article").click(function (e) {
            InitializeDialog($("#news"), $(this).attr("href"));
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#news").dialog("open");
         });


        //Method to Initialize the DialogBox
        function InitializeDialog($element, page) {

            $element.dialog({
                                autoOpen: true,
                                width: 400,
                                resizable: false,
                                draggable: true,
                                title: "Update",
                                modal: true,
                                show: 'fold',
                                closeText: 'x',
                                dialogClass: 'alert',
                                closeOnEscape: true,
                                position: "center",
                                open: function (event, ui) {
                                    $element.load(page);
                                },

                                close: function () { 
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
              });
        }
    });
```

This works for the first article in the list - the dialog opens, but the orther articles open in a separate page. I am assuming this is because the ids are not unique.

My question is more so how to create a generic jQuery function for any id (say, article1, article2, etc.).

I've had about 20 minutes of training on jQuery, so I am shooting in the dark on where to look.

Thanks.

Comment: IDs *really* should be unique in your DOM.

Comment: @Erik: You might be interested in my jQuery plugin, dialogWrapper: https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/dialogwrapper/wiki/Home  It simplifies dynamic creation of dialogs.

Comment: Ideally, you should use class="article" for each of those links and use $('.article') for event binding.

Comment: IDs *MUST* be unique. Otherwise use a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This works for the first article in the list - the dialog opens, but
>   the orther articles open in a separate page. I am assuming this is
>   because the ids are not unique.

You're right, having 2 or more elements with the same ID is invalid HTML and will cause you all sorts of problems.

Remove the `id` attribute and use a `class` attribute instead:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/Updates/LoadArticle?NewsId=3" class="article">Article 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Updates/LoadArticle?NewsId=2" class="article">Article 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Updates/LoadArticle?NewsId=1" class="article">Article 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then instead of:

```
$("#article").click()
```

Use:

```
$(".article").click()
```

Comment: +1. If you have multiple elements with the same ID value, your $('#article') selector is only going to return the first matched element, not all the elements with that ID. This is because the concept of "all elements with a particular ID" in itself is wrong.

Comment: Works perfectly. So simple, I must bang head to pay for my sin of stupidity. :)